# Center 2 floating images

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, center

I want to center 2 images I've set display to block and margin 0 but nothing happens, I've tried the margin on the different divs but also no result. I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong,

this is the css:

```
#partners {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 500px;
margin: auto;
display: block;
}

#partners h2 {
color: #000000;
font-family: "helvetica";
font-size: 36px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 110px;
}

.partner1 {
float: left;
padding: 0px, 50px, 0px, 50px;
margin-top: 125px;

}

.partner1 img {
width: 300px;
}

.partner2 {
float: left;
padding: 0px, 50px, 0px, 50px;
margin-top: 125px;
display: block;
}

.partner2 img {
width: 300px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Share your HTML, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assuming your markup here, but you want to add `text-align: center` to the parent, then make the child block elements `display: inline-block`, then those elements will be centered in the parent.

You also don't need commas between the padding amounts, and I consolidated some of your CSS.

```css
#partners {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 500px;
margin: auto;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}

#partners h2 {
color: #000000;
font-family: "helvetica";
font-size: 36px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 110px;
}

.partner1, .partner2 {
padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
margin-top: 125px;
display: inline-block;
}

.partner1 img, .partner2 img {
width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: @LaurensvanVliet awesome, np. Be sure to vote up answers that are helpful and accept an answer (the checkmark by answers) once you feel your issue is resolved.

Comment: will do, also if I want to add more pictures do I have to only add . partner3, partner4 etc. at the last 2 snippets?

Comment: @LaurensvanVliet if they're all going to have the same style, you should give all of those elements a class of `.partner`, too, then you can just style `.partner` instead of listing all of the individual `.partner[number]` classes.

Comment: Okay that will answer all my questions for now... Thanks for the help.